# looping through a file in node.js between two files

Tags: node.js

Need help on how I can loop through a file line by line between two lines with specific values. I am able to read line by line but not able to loop between two lines with specific value

E.g

> Date
>
> start_of_data
>
> data1
>
> data2
>
> end_of_data
>
> more data1
>
> more data2

Need to get all lines between start_of_data and end_of_data. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are new to stackoverflow  and node.js so people are down voting your question for the reason "that without putting any effort you are simply looking for somebody who can do your work"

I'm posting the answer so that you understand another way of doing it and also refrain from asking such questions going forward without doing enough research and not putting any effort

**NOTE:** This answer is not just about looping but using a good interface called readline. This is very good when your file is very large as it uses node's stream.

Code:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = 'some.txt';

const start = 'start_of_data';
const end = 'end_of_data';

var write_active = false;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(filename)
});

rl.on('line',function(line){

    //Start and end logic
    if(line == start){
        write_active = true;
    }
    else if(line == end){
        write_active = false;
    }

    //Write between the lines
    if(write_active && (line!=start)){
        console.log(line);
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank you @user3151330 . Yes, I am new to stackoverflow and node.js. I had written the below code and got stuck. Anyway realized what I have missed after reading your code.   

var indi = 'false'

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./input5.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    if (line.includes('start_of_data')) {
        indi = 'true'
    }
    if (indi === 'true') {
        console.log(line)
    }
    if (line.includes('end_of_data')) {
        indi = 'false'
    }
});